# Laravel - how to delete the last two rows of a table

Tags: database, laravel

Pretty simple problem: Every time a function is used, it should delete the last two rows of a certain table. The values in these rows should not be an issue.
I have tried different things, for example

```
DB::table('xy')->latest()->delete(); //
```

In order to delete one row. It however deletes every row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using [take](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#ordering-grouping-limit-and-offset)

```
DB::table('xy')->latest()->take(2)->delete();
```

Answer (score 1):

*latest()* will only work if your table has a *created_at* column, if it doesn't, try

```
DB::table('xy')->orderBy('id', 'desc')->limit(2)->delete();
```